# doctrine native sql query update

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I need help.  I need to get the result of a update sql query using doctrine 1.2

I googled and I found a way to make a native sql query using doctrine

```
$preparequerystring = "UPDATE mdw_reportes_operacion SET mmaplicado = 2.742495126705653 WHERE id = 5294;";
         $con = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->connection();
         $st = $con->executeUpdate($preparequerystring,array(false));
         print_r($st);
```

I would like to know how to retrieve some information about the query I'm executing. I've tried with

```
$result = $st->fetch();
```

but it returns a 500 internal server error.

What is the right way to retrieve information about the query when performing an UPDATE query?

Comment: fetch is for a select query, to return the results. An update does not produce any results.

Comment: @MarcB best answer so far. But is there anyway to get some answer if the query was successful or not?

Comment: You should not do Native Update/Insert as it is what `Doctrine ORM` is made for `Associations`.

Answer (score 3):

Why not using the [default update from doctrine](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#update-queries) instead of a row sql ?

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->update('MdwReportesOperacion')
        ->set('mmaplicado', '2.742495126705653')
        ->where('id = ?', array(5294));

$rows = $q->execute();

echo $rows;
```

**Edit:**

I didn't know how to retrieve the result from a raw doctrine query, but you still can use pdo query:

```
// update the way you want to retrieve database information
$database = sfYaml::load(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/databases.yml');
$param = $database['all']['doctrine']['param'];
$conn = new PDO($param['dsn'], $param['username'], $param['password']);

// and then perform the query and retrieve the result
$rows = $conn->exec("UPDATE mdw_reportes_operacion SET mmaplicado = 2.742495126705653 WHERE id = 5294;");
echo $rows;
```

Comment: I know is better to use the default update from doctrine but I use raw sql because i have a lot of queries to perform at once.

Comment: Gracias! I'll try it in a few secs